# Problem: My computer Shut down automatically when I try install Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I make a USB boot able for install Ubuntu. My computer shut down when I try install  Ubuntu. I try from live Ubuntu for install but it shut down too.

Comment: Welcome! At what moment does it shutdown? And by shutdown you mean your machine powers off completely?

Comment: Please download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . The ISO file you use to create a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Comment: Once you make a LiveUSB, install it following these steps https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0.

Comment: @guillermo chamorro. Hi. When I try click on the first continue button it display a black screen and  write  something so small. and yes it power off completely. but when I make the USB boot whit "write in DD Image mode" it display "please remove the installation medium then reboot" in black screen. –